# How to remove the <a> and </a> from <a>link</a>

Tags: javascript

How to remove the `<a>` and `</a>` from `<a>link</a>`? via JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove tag around a text node using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369816/remove-tag-around-a-text-node-using-javascript)

Comment: Is it a string or a DOM element?

Comment: Do you use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? Or just plain javascript?

Comment: HTML tags exist only in the HTML source code. JavaScript operates on the DOM, not the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Without jQuery:

```
function GetInnerContents() {
    var tempElem = document.createElement("div");
    tempElem.innerHTML = "<a>link</a>";
    var aTag = tempElem.firstChild;
    return aTag.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(a.textContent), a);
```

where `a` is the reference to that ANCHOR element.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/S79pZ/

Answer (score 0):

[You can use jQuery](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html):

If it's a string:

```
var htmlSource = ...;
var tree = $("<div>" + htmlSource + "</div>");

tree.find('a[href]')
    .replaceWith(function() { return this.childNodes });

htmlSource = tree.html();
```

If it's already in the DOM:

```
$(...).find('a[href]')
      .replaceWith(function() { return this.childNodes });
```

Answer (score 0):

This function accepts any html element, takes all of its children (be they text nodes or other html elements) and appends them to the element's parent.  Then it removes the element.  Without jquery.

```
function removeAnchor(tag) {
  while (tag.childNodes.length > 0)
    tag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag.childNodes[0], tag);
  tag.parentNode.removeChild(tag);
}
```

example of use

```
<a href='dontcare' id='myanchor'>Click me <img src='http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'> Thanks </a>
<script>
removeAnchor(document.getElementById('myanchor'));
</script>
```